# wicket 1.5 not found error message

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I made a ComponentFeedbackPanel for my inputs where I display message for form components. I have inputs for pass change, where you type your old pass, new pass and repeat new pass:

```
final PasswordTextField oldPass = createOldPassField();
final PasswordTextField newPass = createNewPassField();
final PasswordTextField newPassRepeat = createNewPassRepeatField();

add( oldPass );
add( newPass );
add( newPassRepeat );

final ComponentFeedbackPanel oldPassFeedbackPanel = new ComponentFeedbackPanel(OLD_PASS_ERROR, oldPass);
    oldPassFeedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag( true );

final ComponentFeedbackPanel newPassFeedbackPanel = new ComponentFeedbackPanel(NEW_PASS_ERROR, newPass);
    newPassFeedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag( true );

final ComponentFeedbackPanel newPassRepeatFeedbackPanel = new ComponentFeedbackPanel(NEW_PASS_REPEAT_ERROR, newPassRepeat);
    newPassRepeatFeedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag( true );

add( oldPassFeedbackPanel );
add( newPassFeedbackPanel );
add( newPassRepeatFeedbackPanel );
```

It works great when I use build-up wicket validation methods for example: **EqualPasswordInputValidation** return nice message that inputs don't match next to one of the components. However when I create own class that extends **AbstractValidator** and implements **IValidator**:

```
/**
 * Error msgs
 */
private static final String ERROR_WRONG_PASS = "wrong_pass";

(...)

private class UserPassValidator extends AbstractValidator<String> implements IValidator<String>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onValidate( IValidatable<String> arg0 )
    {
        final String oldPass = arg0.getValue();
        if ( !user.getCryptedPassword().equals( CypherUtil.encodeMd5( oldPass ) ) )
        {
            error( arg0, ERROR_WRONG_PASS );
        }
    }

}
```

I get warning that error message could not be locate:

```
Could not locate error message for component: PasswordTextField@profileModifyForm:mp-oldpass and error: [ValidationError message=[null], keys=[wrong_pass, EditPassForm$UserPassValidator], variables=[]]. Tried keys: mp-oldpass.wrong_pass, wrong_pass, mp-oldpass.EditPassForm$UserPassValidator, EditPassForm$UserPassValidator.
```

I tried to put .properties for every single page that might be connected with this form, the page structure looks like this:

```
MainPage
  |
  |---AjaxTabbedPanels (it basically works like from wicket example http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/tabbed-panel?1)
          |
          |---ProfilePanel (extends Panel)
              |
              |---editProfileWindow (a Modal Window, opened on button click)
                   |
                   |---ProfileEditPass (extends WebPage, pageCreator for modalWindow)
                       |
                       |---EditPassForm (extends Form<Void>, class for form)
                           |
                           |--oldPass (PasswordTextField)
                           |--newPass (PasswordTextField)
                           |--newPassRepeat( PasswordTextField)
                           |--oldPassFeedbackPanel (ComponentFeedbackPanel)
                           |--...and so on for the rest
```

Combination for .properties file I tried:

```
mp-oldpass.wrong_pass = "Wprowadzono błędne hasło"
UserPassValidator = "Wprowadzono błędne hasło"
```

And properties files I tried:

```
EditPassForm.properties
ProfileEditPass.properties
ProfilePanel.properties
AjaxTabbedPanels.properties
MemberTemplatePage.properties (its basically a template, extended by AjaxTabbedPanels)
```

Comment: Is `mp-oldpass` the WicketId of the `IValidatable`? If not, have you tried `wrong_pass` or `<wicket:id>.wrong_pass` in properties? Putting this resource in the panel that's using the Validator should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following to your log4j.properties file to display more verbose information about resource localization:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.wicket.resource=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.wicket.Localizer=DEBUG
```

With that, you will see exactly which property files are tried. For validators, `YourWicketAppClass.properties` in the same folder/package as your `YourWicketAppClass` class should work.

Comment: After some experiments, with logger help I discovered that the message is created inside the pageCreator of the modal window (in my case **ProfileEditPass** and the value is <wicket:id>.wrong_pass, thanks for help!

Comment: where is the log4j.properties to find? I'm using log4j but I dont find it's properties' file..

Comment: If you create a Wicket quickstart project, you will find the file in src/min/resources. Essentially, it needs to be in WEB-INF\classes\ in your WAR or the root of your JAR.